# Non-linear Least Squares Optimization Library for C

Tags: c, optimization, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

I'm looking for a library in C that will do optimization of an objective function (preferrably Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm) and will support box constraints, linear inequality constraints and non-linear inequality constraints.

I've tried several libraries already, but none of them do employ the necessary constraint types for my application:

- [GNU GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (does not support constraints at all)
- [cMPFIT](http://www.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/cmpfit.html) (only supports box constraints)
- [levmar](http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/) (does not support non-linear constraints at all)

I am currently exploring [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt), but I'm not sure if I can achieve a least-squares approach with any of the supplied algorithms.

I find it hard to believe that there's not a single library supporting the full range of constraints in this problem, so I guess I did a mistake somewhere while googling.

I recently discovered I can call Matlab functions from C. While that would solve the problem quite easily, I don't want to have to call Matlab functions from C. It's not fast in my experience.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you update us on what you've done? Thanks.

Comment: I went with NLopt. It supports lots of options and the implementation proved very capable for my project.

Comment: Does NLopt uses Levenberg-Marquardt?

Comment: As far as I know / remember, no it does not.

Comment: A question asking about a library that mods haven't closed!?!? There's hope for SO after all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach I finally followed is the following:

- I used [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) for the optimization and the objective function **was constructed to compute the squared error** of the problem.
- The algorithm that showed the most promising results was **COBYLA** (Local derivative-free optimization). It supports box constraints and non-linear constraints. The linear inequity constraints were introduced as non-linear constraints, which should be generally feasible.

Simple benchmarking shows that it does converge a little slower than a Lev-Mar approach, but speed is sacrificed due to the need for constraints.

Answer (score 7):

Some time ago I was researching the state of C/C++ least squares fitting libraries. I noted down a few links, including the ones you gave and also:

- [ALGLIB/optimization](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/) -- Lev-Mar with boundary constraints.
- [WNLIB](http://www.willnaylor.com/wnlib.html)/wnnlp -- a constrained non-linear optimization package in C (general optimization, not least squares). Constraints are handled by adding a penalty function.

I haven't used any of the libraries yet, but NLopt seems the most promising for me. It would be great if it had specialized interface and algorithms for (weighted) least-squares fitting.

BTW, does your note about Matlab mean that it has Lev-Mar with non-linear constraints?

Comment: WNLIB sound interesting, I will check it out. As for Matlab, to my knowledge the Lev-Mar algorithm does not support non-linear constraints but you can easily implement a least-square approach to a problem using fmincon(). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### MPFIT: A MINPACK-1 Least Squares Fitting Library in C

MPFIT uses the Levenberg-Marquardt technique to solve the least-squares problem. In its typical use, MPFIT will be used to fit a user-supplied function (the "model") to user-supplied data points (the "data") by adjusting a set of parameters. MPFIT is based upon MINPACK-1 (LMDIF.F) by More' and collaborators.

[http://cow.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/cmpfit.html](http://cow.physics.wisc.edu/%7Ecraigm/idl/cmpfit.html)

Answer (score 0):

[OPTIF9](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/docs/cmlib/uncmin/optif9) can be converted to C (from Fortran) and may already have been by somebody.

If what you mean by box constraints is that it supports upper and lower limits on parameter values, I believe there is a version that does that.

That is a tricky problem, because it means whenever a parameter gets to a boundary, it effectively reduces the degrees of freedom by 1.
It can get "stuck on a wall" when you didn't really want it to.

What we've found is that it's better to use an unconstrained minimizer and transform parameters, via something like a log or logit transform, so that in the search space they are unconstrained, but in the model space they are constrained.

As far as the other types of constraints, I don't know, although one option is, as part of your objective function, to make it get really bad when constraints are violated, so the optimizer avoids those areas.

I've found when I have a really flexible set of constraints, if I want a good trouble-free algorithm, I use [Metropolis-Hastings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis-Hastings_algorithm).
Unless I'm wrong, if it generates a sample that violates constraints, you can simply discard the sample.
It takes longer, but it's simple and always works.