# Solver for sparse linearly-constrained non-linear least-squares

Tags: solver, sparse-matrix, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization

Are there any algorithms or solvers for solving non-linear least-squares problems where the jacobian is known to always be sparse, and the solution is constrained with either:

1. Linear equality constraints and box constraints
2. General linear inequality constraints

Comment: You might want to ask this at http://math.stackexchange.com since your question is language-agnostical and about mathematical algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390979/solver-for-sparse-linearly-constrained-non-linear-least-squares

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out existing Open source codes like the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html) Project and also a modified LAPACK-type library [Template Numerical Toolkit](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/overview.html), which contain good support for sparse matrices. You can always modify them to suit your specific needs as well.

Additionally, you can check out this thread 
[Non linear least squares library in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403282/non-linear-least-squares-optimization-library-for-c?rq=1)